# Why my code gets returned after scanning 1st char?

Tags: c

Why my code gets returned after scanning 1st char?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
char kind; char neutered;

printf ("If Dog enter D, If Cat enter C, If Bird enter B, If reptile enter R\n");
printf("\nEnter the kind of Animal: ");
scanf ("%c" , &kind);
printf ("\nIs the Animal neutered? If YES enter 'Y' If NO enter 'N': ");
scanf ("%c" , &neutered);

if (kind == 'D' && neutered == 'Y')
printf ("\nInsurance fee for neutered dog is $40");

else if (kind == 'D' && neutered == 'N')
printf ("\nInsurance fee for non neutered dog is $50");

else if (kind == 'C' && neutered == 'Y')
printf ("\nInsurance fee for neutered cat is $450");

else if (kind == 'C' && neutered == 'N')
printf ("\nInsurance fee for non neutered cat is $65");

else if (kind == 'B' || kind == 'R')
printf ("\nInsurance fee for a bird or reptile is $0");

return 0;}
```

**Output:**
If Dog enter D, If Cat enter C, If Bird enter B, If reptile enter R

Enter the kind of Animal: D

Is the Animal neutered? If YES enter 'Y' If NO enter 'N':

Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time: 7.031
Press any key to continue.

Comment: Short summary of the suggested duplicate: Add a space before `%c` in the `scanf` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `scanf` doesn't consume the newline, so you can use `getchar()` after the first `scanf` to swallow it.

```
scanf ("%c" , &kind);
getchar();
printf ("\nIs the Animal neutered? If YES enter 'Y' If NO enter 'N':");
scanf ("%c" , &neutered);
```